# Yum no está instalado

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, yum

Tengo un problema con el comando yum. Estoy entrando al appliance del Ca api gateway, que está con una plataforma soportada en Centos, y no puedo instalar `yum` sin el comando `yum` y sé que más de uno de ustedes diría que estoy loco pero es que no sé si esto se debiese a un problema de instalación o algo por el estilo.
[image: no man entry for Yum]

Comment: "Sé que mas de uno de ustedes diría que estoy loco" jaja. A mi también me llegaba a pasar eso por la mente.

Answer (score 2):

`yum` es un programa que manipula de forma inteligente los paquetes de instalación, localiza dependencias, descarga paquetes, etc. `rpm` es una herramienta que se encarga de manipular específicamente el paquete `.rpm` que le indicas. Es análogo a `apt-get` y `dpkg`.

Si quieres instalar `yum` necesitas descargarlo y luego instalarlo con `rpm`

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846011/install-yum-in-centos7) se sugiere que puedes hacer algo por el estilo.

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh yum-3.4.3-154.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
```

Ahí, `rpm` recibe los parámetros `-i` que instala el archivo (paquete) dado, `-h` y `-v` que te muestran la información de la instalación de forma verbosa y agradable.

De `rpm(8)`

> ```
>   -h, --hash
>           Print 50 hash marks as the package archive is unpacked.
>           Use with -v|--verbose for a nicer display.
> ```

Aunque puedes descargar la versión que más se acomode a tu sistema.

Y de cierta manera, al hacer todo esto, estás haciendo lo que haría en esencia YUM. Localizas el paquete que quieres - a mano, buscando en la web -, lo descargas - con `wget` -, y lo instalas con `rpm`. Entonces, estás haciendo lo que YUM para tener `yum`. Así que no, no estabas loco :) .